# Non optional expression of type NSDictionary used in a check for optionals. Error

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting this alert, while I am trying to load the .plist file. Any suggestion.  `

```
filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: Constants.kCPECardHeaderAttribute, ofType: "plist")
```

And using NSDictionary to load the contents of the file as follows:

```
guard let fileContentArray:NSDictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: filePath!)! else{
            return
        }
```

and I am getting this error. Any help?[image]
`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove `!` after `NSDictionary(contentsOfFile:)`

```
guard let fileContentArray = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: filePath!) else {
    return
}
```

Both `guard-let-else` and `!` are removing optionals. There is no need to use them both for the same optional.

You could actually use the same pattern for both optionals:

```
guard
    let filePath = filePath,
    let fileContentArray = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: filePath)
else {
    return
}
```

As a side note, it's not common to name variables of *dictionary* types as *arrays*.

Comment: my filePath is of type String?, so removing ! from filePath gives me this alert "Value of optional type String? , not unwrapped" did you mean to use ...

Comment: @KumarUtsav Where did I say that you should be removing it from `filePath`?

Comment: Oh, the fileContentArray was an array earlier, but the client demands , made the plist file return dictionary instead of array. No doubt, I will refactor the name, once the issues are resolved.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: The variable name  *fileContent**Array*** and the expected type ***...Dictionary*** is confusing and a contradiction in terms.

You have to pass an optional to use optional bindings, the exclamation mark unwraps the optional which would make the check meaningless. Remove the second `!`.

However it's highly recommended to use the URL related API and `PropertyListSerialiation` to get a native Swift collection type:

```
if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource:Constants.kCPECardHeaderAttribute, withExtension: "plist") {
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        let fileContentDictionary = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, format: nil) as! [String:Any]
        print(fileContentDictionary)

    } catch {
        fatalError("Bad Design! This should never happen").
    }

}
```

Comment: It is because Xcode doesn't refactor swift code. Literally it was an array only, the client demand made them return dictionary instead. I am in the phase of resolving errors and crashes and then at last giving proper names. Yes, your point is right.

Answer (score -1):

It's because you're using the '!', if you want to check if it's optional you should use ? instead and give it a type that you want.

For Example

```
guard let fileContentArray:NSDictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: filePath) ? String else{
        return
    }
```

Comment: What is that `String` before the `else`? And, also, you can remove the explicit type in the constant definition, it's implicit.

Comment: I'm just giving an example that they could check if it's a certain type. It doesn't need to be there.